# Heavy swapping on oracle 12.1.0.2

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am getting following error. My DB version is "Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production" and i have already gone through Doc ID 1919850.1. I want to know if there is any way to avoid swapping.

```
WARNING: Heavy swapping observed on system in last 5 mins. pct of
memory swapped in [1.80%] pct of memory swapped out [3.26%]. Please
make sure there is no memory pressure and the SGA and PGA are
configured correctly. Look at DBRM trace file for more details. Errors
in file /oradb/oracle/diag/rdbms/PROD/PROD/trace/PROD_dbrm_7340532.trc
(incident=16875): ORA-00700: soft internal error, arguments:
[kskvmstatact: excessive swapping observed], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [] Incident details in:
/oradb/oracle/diag/rdbms/PROD/PROD/incident/incdir_16875/PROD_dbrm_7340532_i16875.trc
Tue Jun 16 09:41:47 2015 Dumping diagnostic data in
directory=[cdmp_20150616094147], requested by (instance=1,
osid=20120017 (DBRM)), summary=[incident=16875]. Tue Jun 16 09:41:50
2015 Sweep [inc][16875]: completed Sweep [inc2][16875]: completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have configured hugepage on that server which solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clearly that memory lack, if server memory has enough free space, try to increase SGA (and PGA) max size, if server has less memory, consider add one or increase `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` (only necessary).

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to increase SGA and PGA you need to have memory, ...
If you set hugepage, the map table (table that managed by processes) will be consume less memory automatically we have more memory to increase PGA & SGA