# No more data to read from socket in Orcale12c , after reading half of the table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a procedure 
in this I am iterating over a table say "emp" which has 47 records,
For each row of emp I have to loop a cursor and cursor has at max 5 records .
and then I am calling another pl/sql function where I am again iterating for different cursor and trying to populated two tables say ,temp_emp,temp_emp_a,

The problem which I am facing is ,my function is able to read 29 rows of emp and able to populate temp_emp and temp_emp_a, after that it is throwing exception "No more data to read from socket"

Note- I am not seeing any ora code for this .
things we have tried is ->
increased the pool capacity

Please share your advices on this ,I am really stuck

Comment: These generic errors usually happen where there's a serious database error, causing the process to crash before it could even throw an error.  If that's the case there will be a trace file on the database server with details about the real error message.  Look for that file and add the information here.  You may need a DBA to help you find the file.

Comment: Is you DB remote or local on your PC ?

Comment: Seryan - DB is remote

Comment: @Rama Tripathi if you have a DBA, ask him to check TNS listener and your ping, this problem comes usually from network instability, or you can do it yourself using tnsping utility located in your oracle\home directory during sql statement execution. [how to use tnsping](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG378)

Comment: @JonHeller -> DBA found this ,
ORA-00700: soft internal error, arguments: [kskvmstatact: excessive swapping observed], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
I am not able to still understand what is the problem .

Comment: and He is also saying that it is expected behavior.

Comment: these are no other errors in trace logs

Comment: show your DBA this [post ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855804/heavy-swapping-on-oracle-12-1-0-2), as I understand, problem can be in memory manage. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me,I solved this issue,removing some nested cursors and optimized my code wherever I could .
Thank you everyone for your responses